# unpack function not giving similar result

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I have a binary file and to get the content I have used "unpack" function.

My script can run for both 32 bit exe or 64 bit exe. Hence I have used the following code :

```
if ( $ENV{PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE} eq 'x86' )
{
    @data = unpack( "LL8", $binary );
} 
else 
{
    @data = unpack( "Q8", $binary );
} 
    print Dumper \@data;
```

But when I am executing the same using 32bit Active perl and 64 bit Active perl compilers, I am getting different results:

32-bit:

> $VAR1 = [
>             129864071,
>             0,
>             47193587,
>             0,
>             16448777,
>             0,
>             41067198,
>             0,
>             129
>           ];

64 bit:

> $VAR1 = [
>             129864071,
>             47193587,
>             16448777,
>             41067198,
>             129,
>             365173507,
>             25208052,
>             152155982
>           ]

What may be the reason for this difference? How can I make them similar while still using the 32bit unsigned long and 64bit unsigned quad values ?

Comment: Got the careless mistake I made here ---
I should put it as 
          @data = unpack( "(LL)8", $binary );
Then only I am using 32 bits to be interpreted as 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, you could use a parenthesized `(LL)8` specification.

Answer (score 6):

The `LL8` specification means 'unpack 9 unsigned 32-bit quantities'.

The `Q8` specification means 'unpack 8 unsigned 64-bit quantities'.

It is not surprising that you are getting different results since you are asking for different results.

I suppose you can use `L16` (or `(LL)8`, though the net result is the same) if you want to unpack 512 bits of data.